# chrome console popups automatically when changing and creating new tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am really getting irritated,chrome console popups automatically each time I create new tab or change tabs.I don't want to uninstall chrome to lose all my important browsing history and bookmarks.Further,I also tried uninstalling and installing chrome before.After fresh install this problem appears after some time.What to do?

Comment: This is a question for http://superuser.com. Anyway AFAIK the devtools console can never pop up by itself so there must be something that shows it explicitly like maybe an extension or something else.

Comment: I guess, you are using some extension which changes new tab appearance, I got this problem when I developed one.

Comment: Did you try to disable all the extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked Developer Mode on top of extensions on setting and it stopped.Now everything is fine.